# Need to access a variable outside of a jQuery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a json string that Looks like this

```
var jsonString = '[{"name":"John Smith","uid":1234,{"name":"Susie Something","uid":4567"}]';
```

I'm making a function that will return all the UIDs seperated by commas. So for example:
1234,4567.

What I do now is this

```
function getUIDS(json){
var uids = '';
parsed = JSON.parse(json);

$.each(friends, function() {
        uids = uids + this.uid.toString() + ',';
 });
 reuturn uids;

}
```

However, nothing returns. How can I access a variable that was created by a jquery thread, outside of the jquery thread.

Comment: First, your jsonString is not well-formed.

Comment: Maybe nothing returns because of `reuturn`? Furthermore, check the JSONstrings. Third, you should parse the JSON before you can use it as an object.

Comment: Fourth, you're iterating over `friends` (which is not defined), not `parsed`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass parsed instead of friends, if this is complete code and friends is not defined anywhere

```
function getUIDS(json){
var uids = '';
parsed = JSON.parse(json);

$.each(parsed, function() {
        uids = uids + this.uid.toString() + ',';
 });
 reuturn uids;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing your json:

```
var jsonString = '[{"name":"John Smith","uid":1234},{"name":"Susie Something","uid":4567"}]';
```

And change your code slightly:

```
function getUIDS(json) {
   var uids = '',
       friends = JSON.parse(json);

   $.each(friends, function() {
       uids += this.uid + ',';
   });

   return uids;
}
```

The important parts are looping over `friends` and spelling `return` correctly.

You should also consider using `join` as suggested by someone. That will make sure you don't get a trailing "," at the end of your `uids` string (unless that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function getUIDS(json){
  var uids = [];
  var friends = JSON.parse(json);

  $.each(friends, function(i) {
     uids.push(friends[i].uid);
  });

  return uids.join(',');
}
```

**Problems in your code were:** (See code comments)

```
function getUIDS(json){
var uids = '';
parsed = JSON.parse(json);

$.each(friends, function() { // using friends instead of parsed
        uids = uids + this.uid.toString() + ','; // using this here
 });
 reuturn uids; // spelling mistake for return keyword

}
```